# How to check if a RichView is empty on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

A have a question about Delphi and the component RichView.

**How can I check if a RichView is empty?**

I need to know if the user typed something or inserted anything into the RichView component.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I gues you could probably achieve this by checking value of LineCount and ObjectCount properties of your Rich View.

Comment: Simply use the `Modified` property.

Comment: @Tom, but what if the user entered something and deleted that after? Or the control was not empty at the program start?

Comment: Thank you @Victoria for the "challenge". I was short on purpose as I first wanted to see if OP has any interest in better solutions. The highlited question is **How can I check if a RichView is empty?** That can be detected by moving caret to end of document, and checking offset. That serves the same purpose as the horrible streamin excersise, just so much easier. Adding and deleting would be triggered "falsely" with checking the modified flag, I admit, personally I would like to check the mod. The `Modified` flag would correctly detect adding (like *typing something or inserted anything*).

Comment: Oh, and a minor detail, if e.g. loading a file would trigger the `Modified` flag, it can be reset, after the loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, @BMS answer worked for me!

I had to adapt your function to my program, because the function ItemCount didn't work for me, so **I changed the function to this and worked very well**:

```
function MyProgram.isEmpty(RView: TbsRichView): boolean;
var AStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  AStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    RView.Editor.SaveTextToStream('', AStream, 0, false, true);
    AStream.Position:= 0;
    Result:= AStream.Size = 0;
  finally
    AStream.free;
  end;
end;
```

In this function I just check if the result is 0. If it is equal to 0, it means the user didn't typed anything, or delete what was wrote previously. So **I can check if the RichText is empty or not**. In my program, the RichText can't be empty to save the form.

Comment: So `GetTextLen = 0` didn't?

Comment: @Victoria, I did a test but unfortunately it didn't work for me. This function always returns zero in my program.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the [**GetTextLen**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.GetTextLen) method:

```
function IsRichViewEmpty(Control: TCustomRichView): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Control.GetTextLen = 0;
end;
```

It's because [**TRichView**](https://www.trichview.com/features/trichview.html) handles the [**WM_GETTEXTLENGTH**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632628(v=vs.85).aspx) message in its own way, so I believe (haven't tested, just checked the source), that it's enough (there's the **rvflCanProcessGetText** flag which would prevent getting the text length, but that one is included when the [**TRichView**](https://www.trichview.com/features/trichview.html) control is created).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, i hope this will help u:

```
function TRichViewEditFrame.isEmpty: boolean;
var AStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := false;
  if TRichViewEdit(RichEditEntete).ItemCount = 0 then exit;
  AStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TRichViewEdit(RichEditEntete).SaveTextToStream('', AStream, 0, false, true);
    AStream.Position:= 0;
    Result:= AStream.Size = 0;
  finally
    AStream.free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why so clumsy code? Simply use the `Modified` property.